# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'paramstyle'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pygtk, py2exe

I'm trying to make a .exe for my pygtk app.
I'm using pygtk+glade, gtkbuilder, sqlalchemy , sqlsever ,pyodbc connector... But the log file that is created for the py2exe when i try to run the .exe created with py2exe, has this bug:

```
\modConfiguracion\main_config.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\ext\sqlsoup.pyc", line 546, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\schema.pyc", line 2355, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\schema.pyc", line 2428, in _bind_to
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.pyc", line 338, in create_engine
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.pyc", line 69, in create
  File "sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.pyc", line 246, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.pyc", line 41, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.pyc", line 1151, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\default.pyc", line 129, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'paramstyle'
```

Line 30 of my code is:

```
self.db = sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup.SqlSoup('mssql://'+var_globales.user+':'+var_globales.passwd+'@'+var_globales.server+'/'+var_globales.base+'')
```

Comment: What happens when you run the raw Python, rather than turning it to an `exe` first?

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy do you have?  Looking at latest on bitbucket, `paramstyle` is referenced a few lines earlier.

Comment: my project work fine in pydev this bug is only when i make the executable for win32

Comment: the Sqlalchemy version is 0.7.9 , python27

Comment: What dependencies do you have in your setup.py?  py2exe might not be grabbing the same versions of packages as you have installed on your system.  Also, is your setup configured to pull in any dlls or other external dependencies (for example, your DB driver) that you need?

Comment: My setup.py includes:
    'includes':'sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base,gtk,gtk.glade,cairo,pango, pangocairo, atk,gobject, logging,sqlalchemy.connectors.pyodbc,sqlalchemy,sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup'

Comment: Me too(linux python3.6), After change SQLAlchemy==1.3.20 to SQLAlchemy==1.3.19, this error Gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. i was reinstall every my pygtk+python+sqlalchemy enviroment, make changes in the setup.py of py2exe for my app.
thanks a lot...

Comment: Now i tryng to run the dist package generated for py2exe on windowsxp32 and this bug here now:                                  _italic_ **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inicio_class.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "gtk\__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.**

Comment: Finally, I run py2exe in a win32 os and delete the import gtk.glade, and rewrite my code with gtk.Builder() add dlls of a vc++ compiler and everythig works fine.